# Access file in computer from iOS device programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone have any idea how to access files in the mac from a device when the device is connected to the computer via USB?

This is the scenario so far.

We need to run some acceptance tests on device, and to save time, the tests are going to be run using mocktail. And since we have a couple thousand tail files, we can't bundle them and copy it out to the device (it's not practical, and probably bad practise anyways), so, we store the mocktail file in the project directory and not include them in the app.

This works great from simulator, given that the simulator is run on the mac, and it can access the files properly. However, when we tried to run the same tests in the device, it crapped out because it can not find the appropriate tail file (which makes sense). So far, I couldn't find anything to do this programmatically from Xcode.

Is there any way that one can access files in the computer from a device connected to it via USB programmatically in Objective-C?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices do not have the proper drivers to pose as a USB host. You will have to bundle your files as resources in your app, or download them over the air.

Answer (score -1):

AirDrop lets you share photos, documents, URLs, and other types of data with nearby devices. AirDrop takes advantage of peer-to-peer networking to find nearby devices and connect to them:
- Sending Files and Data to Another App.
- Receiving Files and Data Sent to Your App.